# How to combine multiple functions that do the same thing?

Tags: javascript, function, svg

I am working on building an app, and I have about twelve `checkboxes` with `svgs` that appear next to the checkbox when that particular checkbox is checked by the user. Example checkbox below:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="stdyCoord" name="resPos1" value="2" class="optnsArea2">

<label for="stdyCoord">
  <object data='images/icons/White_SVG/checkmark2-svg.svg'
         class='img-responsive titleSVG' 
         type="image/svg+xml" 
         style='display: none' id='svgStdyCoord'>
  </object>
  Study Coordinator
</label>
```

I have this working pretty seamlessly with the below JS function:

```
$('#stdyCoord').click(function (event) {

    $('#svgStdyCoord').toggle();

  });
```

Is there a way to avoid having to write out 12 functions that are the same for each different checkbox? I tried to use if/else statements but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You could use numbers in the ids and then loop through the ids and add the click listener.

Comment: yes there is, what is something unique in all 12 checkboxes? anything which we can target?

Comment: Sounds like you could do it all with CSS `:checked` can help you target when your input is checked, then if the structure is like you shown you can target the <object> with `:checked + label object`.

Comment: @AfzalK. I appreciate your response. All 12 checkboxes have unique id's, if that is what you are referring too.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.
I moved the checkbox inside the label.  That way you don't need an id for the checkbox or a "for" for the label.
I gave the checkbox a class of hasSVG so that we know which ones to give the click handler.

The click function itself just gets the next element after the one that was clicked.  So for the hasSVG checkboxes, that's the object you want to toggle.

```js
$('.hasSVG').click(function (event) {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="resPos1" value="2" class="optnsArea2 hasSVG">
  <object data='images/icons/White_SVG/checkmark2-svg.svg'
         class='img-responsive titleSVG' 
         type="image/svg+xml" 
         style='display: none'>
  </object>
  Study Coordinator
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="resPos1" value="3" class="optnsArea2 hasSVG">
  <object data='images/icons/White_SVG/checkmark2-svg.svg'
         class='img-responsive titleSVG' 
         type="image/svg+xml" 
         style='display: none'>
  </object>
  Space Commander
</label>
```

Comment: thank you! I will give this a-go soon and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own native JavaScript Web Component `<marked-checkbox>`,
Supported in all modern browsers.

drawback of jQuery is code can only operate on **existing** DOM nodes.

Web Components *automagically* upgrade, you can `define` a Web Component any time you want.

```html
<marked-checkbox value="1"></marked-checkbox>
<marked-checkbox value="2"></marked-checkbox>
<marked-checkbox value="3" checked></marked-checkbox>

<script>
  customElements.define("marked-checkbox", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let value = this.getAttribute("value");
      this.innerHTML =
        `<label>` +
          value +
          `<input type="checkbox" value="${value}">` +
          `<span>checked!</span><br>` +
        `</label>`;
      this.input   = this.querySelector("input");
      this.span    = this.querySelector("span");
      this.checked = this.hasAttribute("checked");
      this.input.onclick = (evt) => {
        this.checked = this.span.hidden;
      }
    }
    set checked(state){
      this.span.hidden = !state;
      this.input.checked = state;
    }
  })
</script>

<marked-checkbox value="4" checked></marked-checkbox>
<marked-checkbox value="5"></marked-checkbox>
<marked-checkbox value="6"></marked-checkbox>
```

Comment: "drawback of jQuery is code can only operate on existing DOM nodes." that's not true, jQuery is known for having easy means to do event delegation.

Comment: What I meant was jQuery code can only run on existing DOM nodes. You can't run jQuery and then later add a DOM node with a jQuery clickhandler... you would need to run that jQuery again to apply a click handler. It is not a jQuery limitation, its how JavaScript traditionally runs. A defined Web Component will process any future added DOM node, AND will upgrade existing (HTMLUnknownElement) to be a Web Component. That is why in above code I the ``<script>`` in between DOM.

Comment: No, that's not true  you can very well attach the event handler on the document and then check in the event handler if it did hit your expected element, whether it was already there when the event got attached ot not doesn't matter. That's called "event delegation" and jQuery is very useful at that.

Comment: Cool, didn't know jQuery could do that... or (most likely) I forgot... I only used jQuery for 5 years till 2011 when IE11 was released so I could do ``queyrSelectorAll``

Answer (score 0):

If you place the input element as a child to the label you can use the checked state as a CSS selector and display/hide the object element. Here are two examples. In the second I hide the checkbox itself -- I don't know if that was what you where looking for?

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input~object {
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 1em;
}

input:checked~object {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="resPos1" value="2" class="optnsArea2">
    <object data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMDAgMTAwIj4KICA8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI1MCIgY3k9IjUwIiByPSI1MCIgZmlsbD0ib3JhbmdlIiAvPiAgCjwvc3ZnPg=="
      class="img-responsive titleSVG" 
      type="image/svg+xml">
    </object>
    Study Coordinator
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="resPos1" value="3" class="optnsArea2" style="display: none">
    <object data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMDAgMTAwIj4KICA8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI1MCIgY3k9IjUwIiByPSI1MCIgZmlsbD0ib3JhbmdlIiAvPiAgCjwvc3ZnPg=="
      class="img-responsive titleSVG" 
      type="image/svg+xml">
    </object>
    Study Coordinator
</label>
</form>
```